# Android: How to call Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-capture

Right now I was asked to create a simple application in which a person can take a photo. And that photo will be saved to a particular folder and that folder cannot be accessed by the main gallery. Only that application can access the folder and see the pictures.

My question is, how do you add or call the Camera in the application? What are the steps in taking a photo, capturing a photo, saving it in a folder, and how to stop a photo from saving (like cancel the saving).

Comment: Yes I did. But that answer or link posted in my question didn't appear in google search. Well thank you for giving this a down. You helped people alot. You could just answered it, rather than making newbies look stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of docs on the Android Camera API. You can use Google to find them. Here is a link to a really helpful article on the Camera API.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow the example provided by android

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

the easiest and simple instruction.